# Detect changed style property?

Tags: javascript, css, properties, return-value, mutation-observers

I need to detect changes on css, but I need style property (width. height, backgroundColor ..., etc.) as a variable, meaning only the one that has changed. So I don't need value. I need a style property in the form of a variable, for example in bold:

document.getElementById ('id1'). style.**backgroundColor** = 'red';

document.getElementById ('id1'). style.**color** = 'red';

I tried with MutationObserver (maybe some style filter) ... or maybe there is some other method how to get style property?

```
<h1 id="id1" style="background-color:green;color:blue;">My Heading 1</h1>

<button type="button" 
onclick="document.getElementById('id1').style.color = 'yellow'">
Click Me!</button>

<button type="button" 
onclick="document.getElementById('id1').style.backgroundColor = 'red'">
Click Me!</button>
```

```
const Observep = document.getElementById("id1");

const observerp = new MutationObserver(function() {
// var styleproperty = (backgroundColor or color or width....) 
alert("id1 chenge" + styleproperty);
});

observerp.observe(Observep, {subtree: true, attributes: true});
```

Comment: You should be able to do it with MutationObserver: ```.attributeName === 'style'```.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```js
const Observep = document.getElementById("id1");

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    //console.log(mutation.target.style)
    let styles = mutation.target.style;
    for(style of styles){
      console.log(style)
    }
    if(mutation.attributeName === 'style'){
      alert("style change");
    }
  });    
});

// Notify me of style changes
var observerConfig = {
  attributes: true, 
  attributeFilter: ["style"]
};

observer.observe(Observep, observerConfig);
```

```html
<h1 id="id1" style="background-color:green;color:blue;">My Heading 1</h1>

<button type="button" 
onclick="document.getElementById('id1').style.color = 'yellow'">
Click Me!</button>

<button type="button" 
onclick="document.getElementById('id1').style.backgroundColor = 'red'">
Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: I don't need attributes (style), I need which part of the style has changed: color, width, backgroundColor etc ...

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
<button type="button" onclick="addStyle()"> Click Me!</button>


<script type="text/javascript">

    const elem = document.getElementById("id1");
    var setStyle = { 
        backgroundColor:'green',
        color:'blue',
      }

    function addStyle (){
      for(let prop of Object.keys(setStyle)){
        console.log(prop);
        elem.style[prop.toString()] = setStyle[prop.toString()];
      }
    }

</script>
```